# Jekyll build throws error

Tags: ruby, web, rubygems, gruntjs, jekyll

I'm trying to compile a static site with Jekyll, but it keeps throwing an error when compiling. I was originally using grunt-shell to run the 'jekyll build' command which worked nicely with no errors, but the site wasn't being generated. When I ran 'jekyll build' on it's own then I got an error.

I pushed the project to [Github](https://github.com/ciscoo/Pretty-D2L) to show the setup, maybe that helps.

The specific error, with trace, I'm getting is:

```
PS C:\Users\Francisco\Documents\GitHub\Pretty-D2L> jekyll build -t
Configuration file: C:/Users/Francisco/Documents/GitHub/Pretty-D2L/_config.yml
            Source: ./_pages
       Destination: C:/Users/Francisco/Documents/GitHub/Pretty-D2L/_site
      Generating... C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:145:in `chdir': No such file or
directory - C:/Users/Francisco/Documents/GitHub/Pretty-D2L/_pages/ (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:145:in `read_directories'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:116:in `read'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:37:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:18:in `process_site'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:23:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:7:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/jekyll:77:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:78:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)
>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified `source: ./_pages` in your config file, so Jekyll is looking there for files to read. And as you can see in the trace:

```
No such file or directory - C:/Users/Francisco/Documents/GitHub/Pretty-D2L/_pages/ (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that...Thank you for this!